# Maven 'deploy' cause code repackaging after the signing operation (BAD signature)

Tags: java, maven, deployment, gnupg

I want to deploy an artifact to Sonatype OSS repository.

When I deploy with the following command, the signatures are invalid.

`mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar install gpg:sign deploy`

```
> gpg --verify  target/security-versions-1.0.1.jar.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'target/security-versions-1.0.1.jar'
gpg: Signature made 10/20/15 11:45:50 Eastern Daylight Time using RSA key ID 63E38ACF
gpg: BAD signature from "Philippe Arteau <philippe.arteau@gmail.com>" [ultimate]
```

If I remove the deploy goal, the signatures are GOOD.

`mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar install gpg:sign`

```
> gpg --verify  target/security-versions-1.0.1.jar.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'target/security-versions-1.0.1.jar'
gpg: Signature made 10/20/15 11:54:34 Eastern Daylight Time using RSA key ID 63E38ACF
gpg: Good signature from "Philippe Arteau <philippe.arteau@gmail.com>" [ultimate]
```

I realize that, after the sign operation, **the jars were packaged a second time**.
How can I deploy without compromising the signatures?

Problematic operations:

```
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (default-cli) @ security-versions ---

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Philippe Arteau <philippe.arteau@gmail.com>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID 63E38ACF, created 2013-05-12

[...]

[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ security-versions ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Code\workspace-java\maven-security-versions\target\security-versions-1.0.1.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:addPluginArtifactMetadata (default-addPluginArtifactMetadata) @ security-versions ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar-no-fork (default) @ security-versions ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Code\workspace-java\maven-security-versions\target\security-versions-1.0.1-sources.jar
```

The second part should not be done since the compilation and packaging has already occurs.

Comment: I assume you use an oss-parent from sonatype? Than you should simply run a `mvn clean deploy` and based on the configuration the gpg signing should happen as needed.

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't include any reference to oss-parent or repo specific. I look at the oss-parent `pom.xml` and found a partial response. (see response below.)

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. I've tried all sorts of searching and hackery and can't find a solution.

Comment: @Yepher My temporary solution was the answer I have added below.

Comment: I tried that but did not resolve my issue. I finally just manually released the libraries. This is my pom file https://github.com/SparkPost/java-sparkpost/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

## Configuration

Their is a workaround that need adding yet another snippet of XML in the `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This sample was found in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28294463/89769). Although more generic, the person was probably hitting the same bug.

The complete deployment can be trigger with : `mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar deploy` (**Important:** Do not mention **install** or **verify**)

## Caveat

The configuration make sure **gpg:sign** is run prior the **maven-deploy-plugin**.

A side effect can occurs if **verify**/**install**/**sign** plugin is mention. (`mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar verify install gpg:sign deploy`)
The package will be sign up to 4 times recursively (signature being signed..).

## oss-parent

Having the **oss-parent** reference might trigger **gpg:sign** [because of this](https://github.com/sonatype/oss-parents/blob/master/oss-parent/pom.xml#L136).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run both `install` and `deploy`. Otherwise you will run the packaging steps twice.

I recommend using `deploy` only. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405685/maven-install-and-deploy).

Comment: I tried `mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar gpg:sign deploy` and I have all packages (source, javadoc, pom) signed except the main jar.

Comment: have you tried `mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar deploy gpg:sign`?

Comment: Yes and the archive gets deployed without the signature. (It does not work.)