# Main jar is not signed with gpg when running Maven deploy

Tags: java, maven, gnupg

I am trying to deploy a java package to Maven central repository. For this, I included these plugins in my pom.xml :

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId> 
                <executions> 
                    <execution> 
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals><goal>deploy</goal></goals> 
                    </execution> 
                </executions> 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Then, I run :

```
mvn clean javadoc:jar source:jar gpg:sign deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

The output does not contain any error and my project folder now contains a folder target that is like this :

```
+-- target
|   +-- apidocs
|   +-- classes
|   +-- generated-sources
|   +-- javadoc-bundle-options
|   +-- maven-archiver
|   +-- maven-status
|   +-- myproject.jar
|   +-- myproject.pom
|   +-- myproject.pom.asc
|   +-- myproject-javadoc.jar
|   +-- myproject-javadoc.jar.asc
|   +-- myproject-sources.jar
|   +-- myproject-sources.jar.asc
```

As you can see, there is no myproject.jar.asc file which is kind of the same issue that encountered [h3xStream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89769/h3xstream) in his comments on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241549/maven-deploy-cause-code-repackaging-after-the-signing-operation-bad-signature).
So, I did :

```
gpg -ab myproject.jar
```

And it created a myproject.jar.asc file. I thought I could finally deploy the package but when running :

```
mvn javadoc:jar source:jar gpg:sign deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I saw on Nexus Repository Manager that once again, myproject.jar.asc was missing.

Has anyone an idea on how to deploy this myproject.jar.asc file so I can publish my package ?

(I'm totally new to Java and just followed the steps from [the official documentation](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html)).

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Do not configure maven-deploy-plugin like you did...only use `mvn deploy`....which is not mentioned in the referenced documentation.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I just removed the maven-deploy-plugin from the pom.xml file and ran `mvn clean javadoc:jar source:jar gpg:sign deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true` and myproject.jar is still not signed (no myproject.jar.asc)

Comment: Just try `mvn deploy` nothing else...